# How to draw and scale a bitmap on a canvas using bicubic interpolation in Android?

Tags: android, drawing, resize, bitmap, bicubic

I want to draw a bitmap on a canvas with bigger size than it is. I can use canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, destRect, null); but that gives a poor quality, as the result is pixelated, if the source image is sightly smaller than the destination rectangle.

How can i draw my bitmap using bilinear or bicubic resampling?

Any help would be appreciated, thanx.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to set the FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG flag in your paint.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null); //ugly jaggies unless scale is 1:1, but fast
```

or

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setFilterBitmap();
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint); // pretty but slower (not too slow, usually)
```

The same applies to other (syntactic sugar) forms of the `drawBitmap` method.

There is no documentation anywhere for most of the Android drawing options and neither is there documentation for the underlying native Skia library that does the rendering.  I'd be happier if there were.  You can search the Skia source code on Google Code Search.  Search for Skia and dig into the raw source;  that's the only documentation.

Comment: Had to deal with this now, thanks for pointing out setFilterBitmap!  Just to add a little more info from my findings, the interpolation for filter bitmap flag false is nearest neighbor and true is bilinear.  Was hoping bicubic was available but doesn't look like it.

Comment: paint.setFilterBitmap(); is not too slow, because most of the device/api level is using gpu to do the interpolation.

Comment: Exact same behavior, bit more condensed:  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

Comment: that was not enough for me, I had to use createScaledBitmap and apply those filters too

Answer (score 1):

FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG doesn't work for downscaling in most of the cases.

Good downscaling algorithm (not nearest neighbor like) consists of just 2 steps (plus calculation of the exact Rect for input/output images crop):

1. downscale using ***BitmapFactory.Options::inSampleSize->BitmapFactory.decodeResource()*** as close as possible to the resolution that you need but not less than it
2. get to the exact resolution by downscaling a little bit using ***Canvas::drawBitmap()***

Here is detailed explanation how SonyMobile resolved this task: https://web.archive.org/web/20140228024414/http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/06/27/how-to-scale-images-for-your-android-application/

Here is the source code of SonyMobile scale utils: https://web.archive.org/web/20140227233706/http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/code-example-module/image-scaling-code-example-for-android/

Comment: Those links seem to be down, unfortunately.