# Deeplearning4j : Class file for java.awt.image.BufferedImage not found on Android Studio

Tags: android, keras, javacv, deeplearning4j

I have made an image classification model using Keras in Python which is in **".h5"** format. I am trying to use it in my Android application using Deeplearning4j.

I am facing an issue when I try to do image classification by loading a **Mat** image using [NativeImageLoader](https://deeplearning4j.org/datavecdoc/org/datavec/image/loader/NativeImageLoader.html#asMatrix-org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.Mat-) constructor. The code is as follows :

```
NativeImageLoader nativeImageLoader = new NativeImageLoader(60, 60, 3);
INDArray image = nativeImageLoader.asMatrix(testImage);   // testImage is of Mat format

// 0-255 to 0-1
DataNormalization scaler = new ImagePreProcessingScaler(0, 1);
scaler.transform(image);
// Pass through to neural Net
INDArray output = model.output(image);
INDArray labels = model.getLabels();
```

When the app builds it gives an error at the second line of the code above i.e `INDArray image = nativeImageLoader.asMatrix(testImage);`

I get the following error when I build the apk:

```
Error:(1109, 51) error: cannot access BufferedImage
class file for java.awt.image.BufferedImage not found
```

I tried to find the solution but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6345814/7665986) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33210293/7665986) says that AWT package is not supported in Android.

Please help me with a solution or a work around. Thank you.

Comment: Logged issue here: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/DataVec/issues/248 Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the response @AdamGibson

Answer (score 0):

You have to refactor Deeplearning4j to port the java-awt specific lib to a platform independat java lib with platfrom specific handlers for android and awt/j2se

In the java Deeplearning4j lib you have to hide all java-awt specific classes (like BufferedImage) behind an interface IBitmap and implement that interface for j2se and independantly for Android.

I have done this successfully for exif/icc/ipc metadata processing and implemented interface 
[pixymeta-lib/.../IBitmap.java](https://github.com/k3b/pixymeta-android/blob/gradle-build/pixymeta-lib/src/main/java/pixy/image/IBitmap.java) 
with implementation for 
[j2se pixymeta-j2se-lib/.../j2se/BitmapNative.java](https://github.com/k3b/pixymeta-android/blob/gradle-build/pixymeta-j2se-lib/src/main/java/pixy/j2se/BitmapNative.java)
 and android 
[pixymeta-android-lib/.../android/BitmapNative.java](https://github.com/k3b/pixymeta-android/blob/gradle-build/pixymeta-android-lib/src/main/java/pixy/android/BitmapNative.java)

So I have these packages

- pixymeta-lib

  - transformed platform independant lib where all awt-references are replaced by IBitmap interface
- pixymeta-j2se-lib

  - awt/j2se implementation of IBitmap
- pixymeta-android-lib

  - android implementation of IBitmap

Part of this answer is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763257/android-bitmap-resizing-using-better-resampling-algorithm-than-bilinear-like-l/37924730#37924730)

Comment: We logged an issue thanks for this answer: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/DataVec/issues/248

Comment: Thank you for the response @k3b. I will check it out.