# Resizing an image using the Lanczos algorithm

Tags: android, image, image-resizing

I'm trying to use `Lancsoz` algorithm for resize images in Android. As you know Android uses `android graphics bitmap` and java libraries for image resizing uses `java awt image*` so i cannot use them directly in my app.

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763257/android-bitmap-resizing-using-better-resampling-algorithm-than-bilinear-like-l) and answers. I tried to use the library in accepted answer (libswscale) but i couldn't succeed.

Are there any other libraries or solutions you can offer?

Thanks.

Comment: It is still valid question, take a look at this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763257/android-bitmap-resizing-using-better-resampling-algorithm-than-bilinear-like-l