# Downsizing Android Bitmap always results in jagged edges

Tags: android, image-scaling

I'm seeing very ugly artifacting / jagged edges when I downsize an image on an Android device no matter what I try. I've gone through several potential solutions I found on StackOverflow and blogs, and everything seems to give me similar results.

**Original Image (4096 x 4096):**
[image: original image]

**Scaled Image (214 x 214) (notice the jagged edges):**
[image: scaled image]

What I have tried:

1. Drawing the image to a `Canvas` using a `Paint` with anti-aliasing, and filtering enabled
2. Multiple variations of `BitmapFactory.decode`
3. `bitmap.scale()`
4. [Compressor](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor) - an Android Image Scaling Library

All of the above trials have yielded almost the exact same result. This is such a common problem though, that surely I'm overlooking something, or not doing something properly.

If I use a web-based image-resizer, here is the result:
**What it should look like:**
[image]

What can I do to get the same results as the above image?

Comment: Is the source of the image SVG or bitmap when you put through the "web-based image resizer".

Comment: png. It's the exact same file uploaded and labeled "Original Image". I just double checked, and it appears that StackOverflow doesn't seem to have modified the image.

The original image is 4096 x 4096, and I'm displaying it as 214 x 214px

Comment: This is not an AA problem. It's due to the low-quality filter (algorithm) Android API uses when scaling images. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763257/android-bitmap-resizing-using-better-resampling-algorithm-than-bilinear-like-l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tricky way to (manage to) achieve that only with standard APIs. Just avoid scaling down the bitmap at once.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

:
    
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setScale(0.5F, 0.5F);
while (bitmap.getWidth() > 256)
{
    Bitmap bitmap_half = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), m, true);
    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = bitmap_half;
}

imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Result:

[image: Result]

How this works:

Since the filter is short-ranged (primarily designed for scaling up e.g. bilinear or bicubic), it's useless for scaling down (=discrete resampling) in general cases.
However it does refer neighboring pixels for calculating new pixel colors. So by avoiding too sparse resampling, it's possible to make it work as a smoothing filter for scaling down. maybe.

Comment: This works pretty well. It's not perfect, as it requires the creation of several smaller and smaller bitmaps, but it also achieves it without adding some external native library that's 5+MB.

Comment: 50% is also the perfect scaling number it seems. Anything beyond that and the jaggedness starts to come back.

Comment: Here's a gist of the Picasso Transformer I made to handle this for me - https://gist.github.com/ScottPierce/ca6d29233506695b3ee7ee1174c9485b

Answer (score 2):

The lack of smoothness in the trial image indicate some anti-aliasing is missing.

A relatively quick search show that [Sub-pixel antialiasing rules](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/165/16430) can get complicated.

The next thing is to figure out which tool the "web-based image resizer" used to generate the trial image.

Nine times out of ten (or more) the website would be using FOSS software, which would lead to [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)

A quick run of your source image through ImageMagick with a command like:

`convert SO_source_image.png -resize 5% SO_result.png`

Results in this similar but not exact (205x205 pixels) image:

[image: Converted image]

At this point you could either dive into the algorithms used by ImageMagick (see the [command line options for the variety of methods](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php)) or see if you can get a similar result with an existing port like: [cherryleafroad/Android-ImageMagick7](https://github.com/cherryleafroad/Android-ImageMagick7) or [paulasiimwe/Android-ImageMagick](https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-ImageMagick)

Comment: Looks like the cherryleafroad one stays up to date with each new release whereas the paulasiimwe one hasn't been updated in 4 years. Plus it has auto built binaries too. I even saw that the author just made kmagick  (kotlin) jni bindings :o

Answer (score 0):

BitmapCompat.createScaledBitmap() will downscale at much higher quality. The documentation for the function states: "This algorithm is intended for downscaling by large ratios when high quality is desired"